# PHP: Making array by unserializing a serialized string

Tags: php

how can I make an array by the following serialized string:

```
a:2:{i:1;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:22:"برای تست اول";s:6:"amount";s:6:"600000";s:11:"description";s:31:"فقط برای یک دامنه";}i:2;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:22:"برای تست دوم";s:6:"amount";s:5:"70000";s:11:"description";s:37:"مجوز برای 2 تا 3 دامنه";}}
```

Comment: @GYaN, that was the OP's first question (*"what's type of this code"*). Then responding *"What is your above code"* is not very helpful. Check the answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is called "serialization"

```
unserialize('a:2:{i:1;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:1:"1";s:4:"name";s:22:"برای تست اول";s:6:"amount";s:6:"600000";s:11:"description";s:31:"فقط برای یک دامنه";}i:2;a:4:{s:5:"index";s:0:"";s:4:"name";s:22:"برای تست دوم";s:6:"amount";s:5:"70000";s:11:"description";s:37:"مجوز برای 2 تا 3 دامنه";}}');
```

will return your array.

In particular this string is telling you

`a:2` this will be an array of two elements
`i:2;a:4:` this is the first index (weirdly is not zero indexed) that will contain an array of four elements 
`s:5:"index";s:1:"1"` this is the first element of "innermost" associative array, with a key named `index` (a string of 5 chars basically) and its values "1" (a string with only one char)

and so on...

Comment: @Mahdi98 I don't understand your question